# Accessing mounted drive with jenkins on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, mount

I'm trying to setup jenkins to be able to access a mounted drive (it's not a network drive - it's a local HD, I mount it manuall).
Tried

```
 sudo chown -R jenkins /path/to/mounted
```

But I still get permission denied message when trying to cd into the mounted driver or load files from there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure Jenkins is running as jenkins user?

Comment: Yes, 'whoami' returns jenkins

Answer (score 0):

When you change the ownership of any directory to `jenkins` id & group then you won't be able to access that drive since, you can't switch to `jenkins` id because it is directly used for service and doesn't have a home directory. what you can do is add your user id to `jenkins` group and you will be able to access the directory.

Comment: Who do I add my user id to jenkins group ?

Comment: `sudo useradd -a -G jenkins username`

run above command and replace username with your user id from which you are trying to access the drive

Comment: check the ownership of that group first to make sure it is owned by jenkins group and jenkins id